# How to add two images per slide from mysql (PHP Presentation)?

Tags: php, mysql, phppowerpoint, phppresentation

I am trying to make simple presentation with two images per slide but I don't know how to put 2 images per slide. All images goes to one slide.

This is how it looks
[image]

This is what I want
[image]

Could you please help me with this. This is my code: (THIS CODE IS NOW FIXED)

```
$counter = 0;
$query = "SELECT izvestaji.operacija, izvestaji.ucinak, izvestaji.id, projekti.naziv, operacije.nazivEng FROM izvestaji INNER JOIN projekti ON izvestaji.projekatId=projekti.id INNER JOIN operacije ON izvestaji.operacijaId=operacije.id WHERE izvestaji.datum='$datum' AND izvestaji.projekatId='$projekatId'";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

            // Create a slide
            echo date('H:i:s') . ' Create templated slide' . EOL;


            // Shape
            echo date('H:i:s') . ' Create a shape (rich text)' . EOL;

            $id = $row['id'];

            $query2 = "SELECT img_name FROM slike WHERE izvestajId='$id' AND datum='$datum'";
            $result2 = mysqli_query($con, $query2);

            while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)) {

            if ($counter % 2 == 0) {
                $currentSlide = createTemplatedSlide($objPHPPresentation);
                $shape1 = $currentSlide->createDrawingShape();
                $shape1->setName('Part page');
                $shape1->setDescription('Page');
                $shape1->setPath('../../../../files/izvestaji/' . $project . '/' . $datum . '/' . $row['nazivEng'] . '/' . $row2['img_name']);
                $shape1->setResizeProportional(false);
                $shape1->setOffsetX(75);
                $shape1->setOffsetY(300);
                $shape1->setHeight(400);
                $shape1->setWidth(400);
            } else {
                $shape1 = $currentSlide->createDrawingShape();
                $shape1->setName('Part page');
                $shape1->setDescription('Page');
                $shape1->setPath('../../../../files/izvestaji/' . $project . '/' . $datum . '/' . $row['nazivEng'] . '/' . $row2['img_name']);
                $shape1->setResizeProportional(false);
                $shape1->setOffsetX(495);
                $shape1->setOffsetY(300);
                $shape1->setHeight(400);
                $shape1->setWidth(400);

            }
                $counter++;
            }
     $counter = 0;
}
```

You can see full code [ON THIS LINK](https://www.codepile.net/pile/pv5qVlvL)

Comment: You only create one slide per ID. after your $counter++, add another `if($counter == 2){create new slide; $counter =0;}` - pseudo code of course... Or Nick's answer, cuts out the extra if I added...

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. You should use prepared statements.

Comment: Put a 2x1 table there first and then a photo in each of the cells

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a new slide every two images. Move this line:

```
$currentSlide = createTemplatedSlide($objPHPPresentation);
```

to here:

```
if ($counter % 2 == 0) {
    $currentSlide = createTemplatedSlide($objPHPPresentation);
    $shape1 = $currentSlide->createDrawingShape();
    // ...
```

Comment: This helped me to make new slides in while loop, but didn't sort my images two per slide. See this image https://imgur.com/a/8UzPrDo

Comment: @AleksandarMilosevic are you sure you moved the line to the right place? It should only be creating a new slide every two pictures (when `$counter` = 0, 2, 4, etc.)

Comment: I have edited the code in my questions, see where i made a mistake.

Comment: @AleksandarMilosevic you put in a second copy of the `createTemplatedSlide` code inside the `else` block. That should not be there.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed my problem. And I moved Counter = 0 outside second while loop. https://imgur.com/a/mdDRI6e